# Change 3rd octet of IP in string format using PowerShell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, concatenation

Think I've found the worst way to do this:

```
$ip = "192.168.13.1"
$a,$b,$c,$d = $ip.Split(".")
[int]$c = $c
$c = $c+1
[string]$c = $c
$newIP = $a+"."+$b+"."+$c+"."+$d

$newIP
```

But what is the best way?  Has to be string when completed.  Not bothered about validating its a legit IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your example for how you want to modify the third octet, I'd do it pretty much the same way, but I'd compress some of the steps together:

```
$IP = "192.168.13.1"
$octets = $IP.Split(".")                        # or $octets = $IP -split "\."
$octets[2] = [string]([int]$octets[2] + 1)      # or other manipulation of the third octet
$newIP = $octets -join "."

$newIP
```

Comment: Really like this and validates mine wasn't total garbage.  Didn't realise split would make the array for you so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the **-replace** operator of PowerShell and a look ahead pattern. Look at this script below

```
Set-StrictMode -Version "2.0"
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"
cls
$ip1 = "192.168.13.123"
$tests=@("192.168.13.123" , "192.168.13.1" , "192.168.13.12")
foreach($test in $tests)
{
    $patternRegex="\d{1,3}(?=\.\d{1,3}$)"
    $newOctet="420"
    $ipNew=$test -replace $patternRegex,$newOctet
    $msg="OLD ip={0} NEW ip={1}" -f $test,$ipNew
    Write-Host $msg

}
```

This will produce the following:

```
OLD ip=192.168.13.123 NEW ip=192.168.420.123
OLD ip=192.168.13.1 NEW ip=192.168.420.1
OLD ip=192.168.13.12 NEW ip=192.168.420.12
```

**How to use the -replace operator?**

https://powershell.org/2013/08/regular-expressions-are-a-replaces-best-friend/

**Understanding the pattern that I have used**

The (?=) in \d{1,3}(?=.\d{1,3}$) means look behind.

The (?=.\d{1,3}$ in \d{1,3}(?=.\d{1,3}$) means anything behind a DOT and 1-3 digits.

The leading \d{1,3} is an instruction to specifically match 1-3 digits

All combined in plain english "*Give me 1-3 digits which is behind a period and 1-3 digits located towards the right side boundary of the string*"

**Look ahead regex**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

**CORRECTION**

The regex pattern is a *look ahead* and not *look behind*.

Comment: An interesting solution; why are you forcing strict PS2.0 semantics?

Comment: `(?=\.\d{1,3}$)` is a **lookahead**.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **PowerShell *Core*** (v6.1 or higher), you can **combine `-replace` with a *script block*-based replacement**:

```
PS> '192.168.13.1' -replace '(?<=^(\d+\.){2})\d+', { 1 + $_.Value }
192.168.14.1
```

- Negative look-behind assertion `(?<=^(\d+\.){2})` matches everything up to, but not including, the 3rd octet - without considering it part of the overall match to replace.

  - `(?<=...)` is the look-behind assertion, `\d+` matches one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), `\.` a *literal* `.`, and `{2}` matches the preceding subexpression (`(...)`) 2 times.
- `\d+` then matches just the 3rd octet; since nothing more is matched, the remainder of the string (`.` and the 4th octet) is left in place.
- Inside the replacement script block (`{ ... }`), `$_` refers to the results of the match, in the form of a [`[MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instance; its `.Value` is the matched string, i.e. the 3rd octet, to which `1` can be added.

  - Data type note: by using `1`, an implicit `[int]`, as the *LHS*, the RHS (the `.Value` *string*) is implicitly coerced to `[int]` (you may choose to use an explicit cast).
    On output, whatever the script block returns is automatically coerced back to a *string*.

---

If you must remain compatible with *Windows PowerShell*, consider [Jeff Zeitlin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54910762/45375).

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand what you meant when you said "remain compatible" ?

Comment: @Sau001 - Windows PowerShell (PowerShell 5 and earlier) does not support a scriptblock for the replacement parameter; as the querent did not specify what version of Powershell he was using, this answer is useful - but with the warning that it _won't_ work with older versions of PowerShell (for which mklement0 pointed to my answer, above). My answer _will_ work on PowerShell Core, but may not be the _best_ answer for PowerShell Core, because of the new capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

For complete your method but shortly :

```
$a,$b,$c,$d = "192.168.13.1".Split(".")
$IP="$a.$b.$([int]$c+1).$d"
```

Comment: Yep, better than mine

Answer (score 0):

```
function Replace-3rdOctet {
    Param(
        [string]$GivenIP,
        [string]$New3rdOctet
    )
    $GivenIP -match '(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3}).(\d{1,3})' | Out-Null
    $Output = "$($matches[1]).$($matches[2]).$New3rdOctet.$($matches[4])"
    Return $Output
}
```

Copy to a ps1 file and dot source it from command line, then type

```
Replace-3rdOctet -GivenIP '100.201.190.150' -New3rdOctet '42'
```

Output: 100.201.42.150

From there you could add extra error handling etc for random input etc.

Comment: It's not an explicitly stated requirement, but it's what the OP's own code does; either way, I agree that your answer shouldn't have been down-voted, certainly not without feedback - I get that that's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly different method. [*grin*] i managed to not notice the answer by JeffZeitlin until after i finished this.

*[edit - thanks to JeffZeitlin for reminding me that the OP wants the final result as a string. oops! [*blush*]]*

what it does ...

- splits the string on the dots
- puts that into an [int] array & coerces the items into that type
- increments the item in the targeted slot
- joins the items back into a string with a dot for the delimiter
- converts that to an IP address type
- adds a line to convert the IP address to a string

here's the code ...

```
$OriginalIPv4 = '1.1.1.1'
$TargetOctet = 3

$OctetList = [int[]]$OriginalIPv4.Split('.')
$OctetList[$TargetOctet - 1]++

$NewIPv4 = [ipaddress]($OctetList -join '.')

$NewIPv4
'=' * 30
$NewIPv4.IPAddressToString
```

output ...

```
Address            : 16908545
AddressFamily      : InterNetwork
ScopeId            : 
IsIPv6Multicast    : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal    : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal    : False
IsIPv6Teredo       : False
IsIPv4MappedToIPv6 : False
IPAddressToString  : 1.1.2.1

==============================
1.1.2.1
```